# Is there a closed formula for double integral over $x^ny^m / |x-y|$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I'm looking for a generic closed formula (possibly including finite sums) for integral of form

$$ \int_{-1}^{+1} \int_{-1}^{+1} \dfrac{x^n y^m}{\left|x-y\right|} \space dx \space dy $$

my skills in multiple integrals are pretty rusty, unfortunately, so I have no idea except that for each particular m and n the values should be fairly easy to calculate.

assume that m and n are non-negative integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is infinite (at least the positive part where $x,y >0$). Consider just a neighborhood of $\{x = y\}$.
Let $(t,u) = (x-y, x+y)$, then the integral is larger than something like
$$
\alpha \int_{t = -\epsilon}^\epsilon \big(\int_{u=1}^{\frac{3}{2}} du\big) \frac{1}{|t|} dt
$$
where $\alpha$ is the minimum of $x^n y^m$ in this subregion.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Is it so that 1/|r| integrals in R^n   including zero's neighborhood are finite only for n>1 ?

Comment: Ss far as I know, yes.